# Broad approach to create simple webpage (Foundation + SCSS)

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, frontend, html

This is my first question on this community, so please excuse any errors regarding the structure of this post!

I am starting my first job as a junior web developer on Monday. One of my tasks is going to be a 'splice test' - I will get a mockup of a responsive web page and will have to replicate it as best as I can.

I will have to use HTML, Foundation 6, and SCSS (I am already fairly familiar with these languages but do not have much practice). Any links that I add can be dead (href='#') and no back-end is required.

I am wanting to know what is a recommended method to approach doing this task (I know how to set up Foundation etc and get to a basic index.html).

For example, I am thinking that the very first thing is to look at the mockup and figure out the basic grid structure. Perhaps next would be to create the skeleton divs in html (without actually filling with content). Then next maybe best to start identifying general trends like primary colours, make a scss file and define these variables..?

(I know that a rule of thumb is to start with mobile first, but that will not be required for this page; although it does have to be mobile responsive).

I know answers to this question could be very subjective, but I am so open to considering anybody's opinion here. My lack of experience makes me especially receptive to different ways to doing things and I'd like to have good habits in place going into this industry!

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such strict rule maybe to build great responsive websites... Once you start, I would recommend building up the HTML page, to make the basic structure according to the given requirements and add some basic CSS code to make it mobile responsive at-least to some level.

Once this is done, then put up some color, icons, images etc and finally stack it up with JS you want, if any.

Simplest rule is: HTML first, CSS second, and then the rest.

Good Luck!